# Better way to do conditional-sum on df than for-loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, vectorization

I am doing sum on dataframes with for loop. I know that normaly is not a good idea to loop in R and that it is a better way to do it using sapply or aggregate but I just don t see how to use it in my case .

I want to sum one column based on condition of two columns in an iterative way.

Here is what i want to do in a better way for you to understand:

```
sample  <- data.frame( ID = c("bli","bla","blou","qhq","bidi","bada","bodo"),
        A = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1) , 
        B = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0) ,
        C = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1) 

                  )


 g  <-  NULL 
bli  <- 1:length(sample)
for (j in 2:length(sample)) {
  a <- sum(subset(sample,sample[,c(j) ] ==1 , c(j)))
  for (i in 2:length(sample)) 
    if (bli[j] != bli[i]) {
    b  <- sum(subset(sample,sample[,c(j)] ==1 & sample[,c(i) ] ==1 , c(i)))
    c <- names(sample[j])
    d <- names(sample[i])
    e  <- cbind(c,d,a,b)
    f  <- data.frame(e)
    g <-  rbind(g,f) } 
  else {
    NULL
}

  }
g
```

Thanks

Comment: @akrun - I don't think `combn` will work here - `expand.grid` might be necessary.

Comment: @thelatemail The OP needs to remove the identical elements per row after the expand.grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `expand.grid` (suggested by @thelatemail).  The summary of the code below is:

1. Create an "index" of column names (i.e. "nm1") for which we need all the combinations
2. Try `expand.grid` of "nm1" on itself (`expand.grid(nm1, nm1)`).  The syntax `list(nm1)` is a bit general so that you can create multiple-way combinations by specifying the `times` in `rep`.
3. Remove the rows that are identical ("indx1")
4. Use `sapply` to loop over the rows of "indx1" and subset the "sample" dataset using based on the row index from the loop.
5. Do the `sum` based on the subset based on the first column of "indx1" and `sum` based on whether the elements are both "1" from the subset datasets (`sum(x2[,1]&x2[,2])`)
6. `cbind` the "indx1" with the transpose (`t`) of `sapply` and rename the columns of the output dataset.

   ```
   nm1 <- names(sample)[-1]
   indx <- expand.grid(rep(list(nm1),2),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
   indx <- indx[,2:1]
   indx1 <- indx[indx[,1]!=indx[,2],]
   row.names(indx1) <- NULL
   res <-  cbind(indx1,t(sapply(seq_len(nrow(indx1)), function(i) {
                     x1 <-  unlist(indx1[i,])
                     x2 <- sample[,x1]
                  c(sum(x2[,1]), sum(x2[,1]&x2[,2])) }))
    )
   names(res) <- names(g)
   res
   #   c d a b
   #1 A B 5 2
   #2 A C 5 3
   #3 B A 3 2
   #4 B C 3 3
   #5 C A 4 3
   #6 C B 4 3
   ```

Or even without using `sapply` (would be faster), use `colSums` on both the subset datasets "i1", "i2".

```
 i1 <- sample[indx1[,1]]
 i2 <- sample[indx1[,2]]
 a <- colSums(i1)
 b <- colSums(i1 &i2)
 #in case you have more than two columns
 #b <- colSums(Reduce(`&`,list(i1, i2)))
 res1 <- cbind(setNames(indx1, c('c', 'd')), a, b)
```